# Length of vector $p=a+b+c$ when $a,b,c$ lengths are provided and $a,b,c$ make $60^\circ$ angles with each other

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The problem: Vectors $a$, $b$, $c$ make $60^\circ$ angles with each other. $|a| = 4$, $|b| = 2$, $|c| = 6$. Find the length of $p = a + b + c$.

The only way I can think of $a$, $b$ and $c$ having $60^\circ$ angles with each other is that they form a vertex of a tetrahedron. Then, I can find $|a+b|$ or $|b+c|$ or $|a+c|$ using the law of cosines. But then I can't find $|p|$, because I don't know the angle between the vector I have found and the remaining one.

I would like to get some hints or clues how to solve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would square the given sum:
$$\vec{p}^2=(\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})^2=\vec{a}^2+\vec{b}^2+\vec{c}^2+2\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}+2\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}+2\vec{c}\cdot\vec{a}$$
This is equal $$|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2+|\vec{c}|^2+2|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos(\pi/3)+2|\vec{b}||\vec{c}|\cos(\pi/3)+2|\vec{a}||\vec{c}|\cos(\pi/3)$$

Comment: Ok, so this way I have found that |p| = 10, which is the correct answer in my answer sheet. On what rule/formula is this approach to this problem is based on?

Comment: On the definition of the square of a vector,and the dot-product.

Comment: Do you have an answer sheet?

Comment: Yes, there it says |p| = 10, but nothing about how to come to this solution, that's why I posted this